# How to display UIActivityIndicatorView while a SceneKit Scene loads

Tags: scenekit

The scene load takes about 7-9 seconds. So I need an activity indicator.

I create the spinner like this:

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    spinner.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    spinner.opaque = NO;
    spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    [spinner setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Add the sub view like this:

```
    [sceneView addSubView:spinner];
```

Tried calling in viewDidLoad:

```
[spinner startAnimating];
//load the scene
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

But it spins away forever and scene never loads.

What is the correct way to do this?

**I tried this based on @mnuages response:**

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer willRenderScene:(SCNScene *)scene atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time  {

if ([self spinner] == nil) {
    _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
    _spinner.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    _spinner.opaque = YES;
    _spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    _spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    [_spinner setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.8 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
    _spinner.center = self.view.center;

    [self.view addSubview:_spinner];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_spinner];
    [[self spinner] startAnimating];
}

NSLog(@"BEGIN SCENE RENDER %@",scene);
```

}

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didRenderScene:(SCNScene *)scene atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time  {

[[self spinner] stopAnimating];
[_spinner removeFromSuperview];
_spinner = nil;

NSLog(@"END SCENE RENDER %@", scene);
```

}

But this gets called repeatedly.  And the spinner doesn't show.   And I still see a blank white screen  (the SCNView's initial white background color set in IB, which is changed later to  gray in the viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look at `SCNSceneRenderer.delegate` and `-renderer:didRenderScene:atTime:`

Comment: Revised the original code based on suggestion from @mnuages.  Still  don't see the spinner.

Comment: you should not redisplay the spinner once the view has been rendered  for the first time. When you configure the view, add the spinner and start it. Then when you are notified that the scene was rendered, remove the spinner.

Comment: Starting the spinner in `viewDidLoad` is still a good idea -- you want to use the renderer delegate methods only for catching the first `didRenderScene` message.

Comment: Got it working.  Configured it and started animation in -viewDidLoad  and turned it off in render:didRenderScene:atTime. Thnx.